# getSubtree function in ggtree, no such function

Tags: bioconductor, ggtree

I have installed ggtree package v1.8.2 and I've wanted to use getSubtree function. However I get an suprising error :):

> Error in getSubtree() : could not find function "getSubtree"

Even though I see the fuction in Rstudio Help as a member of ggtree package and as it is mentioned in package description: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/ggtree/man/ggtree.pdf

Direct export from package by :: does not work, too. I've tried also to update, reinstall packages. And there is no such in ls("package:ggtree").
Have I misinterepretted sth or there is no such a function?

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggtree_1.8.2         treeio_1.0.2         ggplot2_2.2.1       
[4] BiocInstaller_1.26.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.12     lattice_0.20-35  ape_4.1          tidyr_0.7.1     
 [5] plyr_1.8.4       grid_3.4.1       jsonlite_1.5     nlme_3.1-131    
 [9] gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.5.0     rlang_0.1.2     
[13] lazyeval_0.2.0   rvcheck_0.0.9    tools_3.4.1      glue_1.1.1      
[17] purrr_0.2.3      munsell_0.4.3    parallel_3.4.1   compiler_3.4.1  
[21] colorspace_1.3-2 tibble_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is not exported and may change or may be removed in a future release.

If you really want to access it, try:

```
ggtree:::getSubtree
```